# AWS braket python sdk: user is not authorized to perform on quantum device

Tags: amazon-braket

I have installed boto3, aws cli, and python-braket-sdk. I have run `aws configure`, and config with my IAM user. My IAM user isn't root user, but it has `AdministratorAccess`, `AmazonBraketFullAccess`, `AmazonBraketJobsExecutionPolicy` policies.

But if I tried to get some quantum device by this command:`aws braket get-device --device-arn arn:aws:braket:::device/qpu/ionq/ionQdevice`, it always return this error:

`An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetDevice operation: User: arn:aws:iam::178363055402:user/hblab-rnd is not authorized to perform: braket:GetDevice on resource: arn:aws:braket::178363055402:device/qpu/ionq/ionQdevice with an explicit deny`

If I run same below python from this link: https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-sdk-python#usage, it also return similar error:

```
import boto3
from braket.aws import AwsDevice
from braket.circuits import Circuit
device = AwsDevice("arn:aws:braket:::device/quantum-simulator/amazon/sv1")
bell = Circuit().h(0).cnot(0, 1)
task = device.run(bell, shots=100)
print(task.result().measurement_counts)
```

Error output:

```
AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetDevice 
operation: User: arn:aws:iam::178363055402:user/hblab-rnd is not authorized to perform: 
braket:GetDevice on resource: arn:aws:braket::178363055402:device/quantum-simulator/amazon/sv1 
with an explicit deny
```

I have already added permissions for Braket, but I can not figure the reason for this bug. Please help

**System information**

- **aws cli**: aws-cli/2.7.11 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
- **Amazon Braket Python SDK version**: 1.25.2
- **Amazon Braket schemas**: 1.10.0
- **Amazon Braket default simulator**: 1.6.2
- **Python version**: 3.8.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. I have activated MFA authorization on my account, but in my `aws cli`, I don't setup it. So I need to setup my `aws cli` by a new account without MFA, or set up MFA for my `aws cli`. Thank you everyone for help

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce this at my end looks like something incorrect with IAM configuration. Can you try using the command `rm -rf .aws` to remove the current credentials and then performing the `aws configure` command once more with a new access ID and key for the same user with attached policies?

And then try running `aws braket get-device --device-arn arn:aws:braket:::device/qpu/ionq/ionQdevice`. Also make sure to set Default region name as `us-east-1` before running this command.